# Toggeling siblilling paragraphs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS question:
My html:

```
<div class="attribute">
    <h1>some header</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="attribute">
    <h1>some 2nd header</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

my js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var attributeHeader = $('.attribute');
  attributeHeader.each(function() {
      $(this).children('ul').hide();
      $(this).click(showDefinition);
      function showDefinition(event) {
          $(this).children('ul').toggle();
      }
  });
});
```

I want to hide to toggle the attributes when people click on the headers.
But instead I ended up toggling them when people click on the div.
I could change the button to click on but then I loose the context in the showDefinition function. How can I do this? I am using jquery here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `next()` to find the next sibling. That way you can target the h1 of the attribute for the event and toggle its next sibling. Here is the code that should work, though I commented out a line that I think is superflous since it keeps hiding the element before toggling it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var attributeHeader = $('.attribute h1');
  attributeHeader.each(function() {
      //$(this).next('ul').hide();
      $(this).on('click',showDefinition);
      function showDefinition(event) {
          $(this).next('ul').toggle();
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer. My case is actually a little bit more complex: 
My html code looks like this: 

I have not only a list to toggle but also a div after the list, so I would like to toggle both of these elements at the same time.  Could you hint me on how to do this?

Comment: I found it: I have to use `nextAll()` instead of `next()` for two HTML elements to toggle together.